# Global callbacks using object functions

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js

i´m integrating an Api which has events that invoke functions which must be in the global space. I´m using backbone to define views and models that respond to those callbacks, which would be the best way to bind that callback so that it invokes the function in the instance of the model for example: 
get an **instance** of something like this

```
  Model.extend({
       thisIsTheApiCallback: function() {
            //DO WORK
       }
  }) ;
```

to behave like this script in the page

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function thisIsTheApiCallback() {
         //DO WORK
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Obviously far from being my native language.

just trying to do window.thisIsTheApiCallback = ModelInstance.thisIsTheApiCallback. Is that a good solution? any other idea?

Comment: If you don't mind having global variables that would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your model to indirectly listen to the global callback, you can use Backbone to forward the event. Keep in mind that every instance of the model you create would get `doSomething` called when the global callback is called.

```
// global callback function
function thisIsTheApiCallback() {
         Backbone.trigger('foo');
   }

// MyModel doesn't need to know about the global callback.
var MyModel = Model.extend({
       initialize:function(){
           this.listenTo(Backbone, 'foo', this.doSomething);
       },

       doSomething: function() {
            //DO WORK
       }
  }) ;
```

Comment: This answer is the best available option in your case IMHO. Instead of triggering events on Backbone itself you can create global event bus object like this: `var eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)` and then use `eventBus.trigger(...)` and `this.listenTo(eventBus, ...)`. You can also attach listener to all events for debugging like this: `eventBus.on('all', console.debug, console)`